# how to prove : there are an infinite number of points on the circle

Tags: number-theory, infinity, formal-systems, provability

I think the follow problem is equal to the problem set 1.16.(a) in  **Principles of Mathematical Analysis (walter ruldin**), And we take (a, b) in $R^2$, X in $R^i$

how to prove : there are an infinite number of points on the circle, 
$$(x - a)^2 + (y -b)^2 = D $$
 change a style 
 z = (x, y) , how to prove there is infinite z . When expand to i dimensions, z = (Z1, Z2, ...., Zn), a fix point X = (X1, X2, ...Xn)
$$(Z1 - X1)^2 + .... +  ( Zi - Xi)^2 = D $$
how to prove there is infinite z . ?  In 2 dimensions, this equal to prove : point on circle is infinite , In 3 dimensions, this equal to prove: point on sphere is infinite. How to prove or we can say describle it in algebraic formalization ?  May be it is a special problem : How to prove a set (which have its contidions or characteristics) is infinite. From my knowledge, we can find 1 to 1 map from my problem set to a infinite set (Like the point on circle maping to the point on line, if can , can the maping using algebraic? While , "the point on line is infinate" should be proved or just take it is truth )

Comment: There is a bijection from a circle to $[0,2\pi)$.

Comment: Are you doing this over the real numbers?  Do you know a criterion for a quadratic equation to have a real solution?

Comment: $\{(a+\sqrt{D} \cos {1 \over n}, b+ \sqrt{D} \sin {1 \over  n})\}_n$.

Comment: @copper.hat , so n is Real numbers?

Comment: I guess there's more to it than, say, noting that for any two distinct points on the circle, separated by angle $<2\pi$, there's always a point between them?  Namely, if one point is angle $\alpha$ and another $\beta$ with $0 \leq (\alpha \ne \beta) < 2 \pi$, then there exists a point at $(\alpha + \beta)/2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that square-roots exist, you can just pick any $x$ in the interval $[a-\sqrt{D},a+\sqrt{D}]$ and then show that you can find a $y$ that satisfies the equation for each $x$. In higher dimensions, you can reduce to two dimensions by setting all but two of the squared terms to zero.

So the question boils down to how do you know $[a-\sqrt{D},a+\sqrt{D}]$ is infinite if $\sqrt{D} > 0$? There are a number of elementary ways of showing this, for example in between any two different real numbers there is a rational number strictly in between.